# POST запрос express

Tags: node.js, post, express

Почему на сервер не приходит объект запроса?
Запрос:

```
fetch('/api/teacher/createTest', {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
    })
        .then(() => {
            console.log('create test', JSON.stringify(this.state));
    });
```

Сгенерированный запрос вроде выглядит нормально:

```
create test {"id":1497705421652,"forGroups":[],"name":"","subscribers":[],"questionsCount":0,"questions":[]}
```

Обработчик на сервере:

```
app.post('/api/teacher/createTest', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

Вот что он выводит(консоль сервера):
[image]

body-parser подключен:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Где тут моя ошибка?

Comment: а в консоле браузера вы видите передачу запроса?

Comment: Заголовок application/json - и всё будет ok

Comment: @MikhailVaysman да, там все в порядке

Comment: @YuriyPo Не помогло, все равно на сервер ничего не приходит

Comment: Что не помогло? Там headers: должен быть объект - https://davidwalsh.name/fetch

Comment: @YuriyPo извиняюсь, не правильно header прописал, все работает, спасибо

Comment: Создать объект new Headers(); потом методом set установить, потом объект в запрос добавить. Короче, проще XHR отправить.

Comment: @YuriyPo я сделал немного по другому, 2м параметром fetch идет объект, там есть параметр  headers который тоже принимает объект, вот туда и записал